# How to create empty file with NSIS

Tags: nsis

In my installer I would like to create an empty file. In linux I would use the touch command, but what's the easiest way to do this in NSIS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#Compile time
!appendfile "$%temp%\compiletimefile.txt" ""

;Or if you need to force the file to be empty
!appendfile "$%temp%\compiletimefile.txt" ""
!delfile "$%temp%\compiletimefile.txt"
!appendfile "$%temp%\compiletimefile.txt" ""


#Run time, method 1
FileOpen $0 "$temp\runtimefile1.txt" w
FileClose $0


#Run time, method 2
File "/oname=$temp\runtimefile2.txt" "$%temp%\compiletimefile.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I wasn't aware of the !appendfile command.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code to create an empty file. Also, it helps a lot for debugging when you place it in any function block.

```
StrCpy $9 "hello world"
FileOpen $8 "$DESKTOP\test_1.txt" w ;Opens a Empty File and fills it
FileWrite $8 "$9"
FileClose $8 ;Closes the filled file
```